# Getting values from seralized array

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using JQuery with an Ajax call to a PHP file that is reading values from MySQL DB.(Wordpress) When the values return to jQuery and I output them to the console this is an example of what I get: a:1:{i:0;i:90;}

How do I access the values 90 from this seralized array using jQuery where 90 will be a different value but always in the same position?

```
$prod = $_POST['item'];
//$mod_prod = substr($prod, 0, strpos($prod, "|"));

//query to get data from the table
$query_Product = sprintf("select meta_value from wp_postmeta Where post_id = '".$prod."' and meta_key = '_upsell_ids'");

//execute query
$result_Product = $mysqli_Product->query($query_Product);

//loop through the returned data
$data_ListRD = array();
foreach ($result_Product as $row) {
    $data_ListRD[] = $row;

}


//free memory associated with result
$result_Product->close();

//close connection
$mysqli_Product->close();

//print_r(json_encode($data_ListRD));

//now print the data
print json_encode($data_ListRD);
```

$data_ListRD I think is an array, how do I unserialize this?

Comment: Added 2 solutions for you ;)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. **DO NOT** use `sprintf` to put data into your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $.parseJSON function or JSON.parse method if you are not using jQuery. But since you receive the data like "{a:1, b:{i:0,i:90}}" (in your example there is typo mistakes), you already receives an object, that is why you do not need to parse it, since it is already not a JSON. For example if you console log your result, it will looks like this:

```
let data = {a:1, b:{i:0,i:90}} //data that comes from AJAX (as an example).
  console.log(data);

//Result
    a: 1
    b: {i: 90}
    __proto__: Object
```

Comment: When I try both methods above I get the following error: jquery.js:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 1